# Waiting for a modaless form to close

Tags: c#, winforms

What I want to achieve is to make a modaless window modal without hiding it first.
This does the job for the start:

```
form.Show();
// do preparation stuff and display in form
form.Visible = false;
form.ShowDialog();
// Cleanup application logic and exit gracefully
```

There are tasks running that do the actual job in the background. The form is used to display the event log.

What I would like is to avoid hiding the form and showing it again as modal dialog. What I have tried (linqpad snippets):

```
void Main()
{    
    var form = new MyForm();
    form.Show();
    // do stuff
    form.WaitForClose();
}

class MyForm : Form
{ 
    private TaskCompletionSource<bool> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

    public MyForm()
    {
        this.Closed += (s, e) => tcs.TrySetResult(true);
    }

    public void WaitForClose()
    {
        var r = tcs.Task.Result;
    }
}
```

But this code is blocking.

This one is working, but I would like to have it more simple:

```
void Main()
{
    var form = new MyForm();
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        form.WaitToLoad();
        // do preparation stuff and display in form
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
           // do bakcground stuff
        });
        form.WaitToClose();
        // Cleanup application logic and exit gracefully
    });
    form.ShowDialog();      
}

class MyForm : Form
{ 
    private EventWaitHandle _loadWaitHandle = new AutoResetEvent (false);   
    private EventWaitHandle _closeWaitHandle = new AutoResetEvent (false);  

    public MyForm()
    {
        this.Load += (s,e) => _loadWaitHandle.Set();
        this.Closed += (s, e) => _closeWaitHandle.Set();
    }

    public void WaitToClose()
    {
        _closeWaitHandle.WaitOne();
    }

    public void WaitToLoad()
    {
        _loadWaitHandle.WaitOne(); 
    }
}
```

I feel I am missing something obvious here.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `.Result` on a task will block until the result can be resolved. Try changing the method to something like this

```
public async Task WaitForClose()
{
    var r = await tcs.Task;
}
```

The you await the call to this and it will yield to other operations while waiting for this to complete.

Comment: This works only if the caller (Main in this case) is also async and I can use await. ´form.WaitForClose.Wait();´ will also block.